# Prove a planar graph is unique up to isomorphisms

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Find a planar graph with 12 vertices and such that all vertices have
degree 5. Show that such a graph is unique modulo isomorphism.

I know we can find the number of faces and edges using Euler's theorem, but how do I do the second part?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Prove that each face must be a triangle.

Next, if you have two graphs with this property, start from a triangle in each of them, call them $u_1,u_2,u_3$ and $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Define  $f(u_1)=v_1,..f(u_3)=v_3$.

Now each edge must belong to a second triangle, otherwise some vertex would have degree $2$, so you can extend your isomorphism, and repeat.

Comment: Perfect hint, thank you.